# Repairing corrupt geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arccatalog

I have an ESRI Geodatabase (Version unknown) which is not displayed in ArcCatalog as a gdb but as a normal directory with a ".gdb" ending. It could be, that whilst it was being unzipped, something got corrupted.

I have tried restoring it with the ArcGIS Pro "repair GDB" Tool but to no avail.

Is there a way of determining what is wrong or missing so that I could repair it?

Comment: Not really. There are too many opportunities for corruption in a failed extract. You need to go back to the source and recapture it for transfer.

Comment: Could it be, that the GDB is for a newer version of ArcGIS than mine?

Comment: No. FGDB hasn't changed since 10.0.

Comment: ...and if it was in fact a Personal Geodatabase??

Comment: personal geodatabase files have a mdb suffix, not gdb

Comment: You could try QGIS

Comment: Please confirm the type of geodatabase that you are working with.